# Row Stores vs Column Stores

Tags: sql, database, storage

Assuming that the database is already populated with data, and that each of the following SQL statements is the one and only query that an application will perform, why is it better to use row-wise or column-wise record storage for the following queries?...

1) `SELECT * FROM Person`

2) `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id=5`

3) `SELECT AVG(YEAR(DateOfBirth)) FROM Person`

4) `INSERT INTO Person (ID,DateOfBirth,Name,Surname) VALUES(2e25,’1990-05-01’,’Ute’,’Muller’)`

In those examples `Person.id` is the primary key.

The article [Row Store and Column Store Databases](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/12/14/row-store-and-column-store-databases/) gives a general discussion on this, but I am specifically concerned about the four queries above.

Comment: You are asking if it's _"better to use row-wise or column-wise record storage? Why?"_, yet you have linked to an article that explicitly discusses _"the differences between row store and column store databases"_! Reduce the broad scope of your question to address a specific issue that concerns or confuses you. As it stands your question links to an article that explicitly answers the questions you are asking.

Comment: @skomisa no no, the article is explaining both concepts, and I read and understand them, but, as I say in the question, what I want to know, is which of them to use, in each particular case. I deduced that the first two are row and third one column but I am not sure about the last one and also I want to confirm all of them.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood what you were asking - my apologies. I have edited your question to clarify the problem. Please check that the changes I have made are appropriate.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite that article with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM` ... queries are better for row stores since it has to access numerous files.

Column store is good for aggregation over large volume of date or when you have quesries that only need a few fields from a wide table.

Therefore:

1st querie: `row-wise`

2nd query: `row-wise`

3rd query: `column-wise`

4th query: `row-wise`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are asking.  You have this statement:

```
INSERT INTO Person (ID, DateOfBirth, Name, Surname) 
    VALUES('2e25', '1990-05-01', 'Ute', 'Muller');
```

This suggests that you have a table with four columns, one of which is an id.  Each person is stored in their own column.

You then have three queries.  The first cannot be optimized.  The second is optimized, assuming that `id` is a primary key (a reasonable assumption).  The third requires a full table scan -- although that could be ameliorated with an index only on `DateOfBirth`.

If the data is already in this format, why would you want to change it?

This is a very simple data structure.  Three of your four query examples access all columns.  I see no reason why you would *not* use a regular row-store table structure.

Comment: He probably want to know the pros and cons of rowstore vs columnstore engines

Comment: yes, @Ayan_84 I know them in general, I know that Due to the fact that a column-based database has each column’s data in a separate file, it is less than ideal for a “SELECT * FROM…” query, since the request must access numerous files to process the request. Similarly, any query that selects a single or small subset of files will probably perform better in a row store. The column store is awesome for performing aggregation over large volumes of data. Or when you have queries that only need a few fields from a wide table. But I want to know exactly what to use for each query above